# Angular problem using third-party component from lazy-loaded module

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I have an Angular project and I want to use a third-party component (FullCalendarComponent), which is declarated in the third-party module - FullCalendarModule) in my own lazy-loaded module.

But the problem is, that the third-party module (FullCalendarModule) uses a BrowserModule, which should not be.

So, my Angular app can use the third-party component (FullCalendarComponent) only in non-lazy-loaded module, because, otherwise it gives an error:

```
Error: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.
```

I have created an issue on their tracker:
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-angular/issues/423

But is there a way to bypass this for now, so I can use it in a lazy-loaded module?

Comment: how do you so sure that the fullcalendar import that module? did you check their source code?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the source code.

Comment: I see the opposite, no code in the library imported that module. Could you link me to the github line that has the code?

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed with v6.0.0 beta 4: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/releases/tag/v6.0.0-beta.4

Comment: I saw that, because I have created the report. But this does not answer to my question.